# RegEx optional group matching

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to create a regex that would encompass both of the following lines:

```
02-09-16  08:57PM                24768 Invoice - Copy.docx

05-14-16  08:49PM       <DIR>          Bin
```

Both are the result of a directory listing. The first being a file which contains the file size.  The second is a directory with no size but contains the type `<Dir>`.

This allows me to capture all of the data into named groups but the first line's size is capture into the Type field:

```
(?<Date>\S+)\s+(?<Time>\S+)\s+(?<Type>\S+)\s+(?<Name>.+)
```

If possible, I'd like to end of with both a Type and Size.  I'm not sure how to look for both of these at the same time but ignore one or the other if one is found.

**Update** : Based on Wiktor's response I've update the Regex and gotten closer :

```
(?<Date>\S+)\s+(?<Time>\S+)\s+(?:(?<Type>\S+)|\d+)\s+(?<Name>.+)
```

Using this I can easily parse both lines.  However first line 24768 end's up in the Type group. Is it possible to have both a Type and an additional Size group? Logic being something like If you run into characters ('`<Dir>`') for example, that is the Type; if you run into numbers (24768) that is the Size

Comment: What about [`^(?<Date>\S+)\s+(?<Time>\S+)\s+(?:(?<Size>\d+)|<[^<>]*>\s*(?<Name>.+))`](https://regex101.com/r/vN3oI8/1)?

Comment: I appreciate the effort but 1. You've removed the Type group altogether and 2 it doesn't work with line one.

Comment: What regex engine? What's your long term goal? That looks Windowsy - use PowerShell to generate the directory listing and make it in an easily parseable format... `dir | Select Name,LastWriteTime,@{N="Directory?";E={$_.PsIsContainer}},Length  | Export-CSV out.csv -NoTypeInfo` or whatever.

Comment: No idea what you want: you speak about Size, but your regex only has Type - that is why I removed it. Please specify what exactly you need to match in these strings and provide exact specifications.

Comment: The long term goal is to be able to parse responses from any number of ftp servers.  Indeed it is Windowsy, Unix response looks entirely different and Linux etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group the type and size captures into a a non-capturing or-group:

```
^(?<Date>\S+)\s+(?<Time>\S+)\s+(?:(?<Size>\d+)|(?<Type>\S+))\s+(?<Name>.+)$
```

The size field will pick up the digits, else you get a type.

Comment: Bra-freakn-vo,  Regex is fairly new to me so much appreciated.